# My localStorage is not saving anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

So this is like a ToDo list site, but when I refresh nothing is saved!
Here are the HTML and Javascript:

```js
localStorage.setItem('myInput'); {
  var save = localStorage.getItem("myInput");
}
localStorage.setItem('myInput2'); {
  var save = localStorage.getItem("myInput2");
}
localStorage.setItem('myInput3'); {
  var save = localStorage.getItem("myInput3");
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-content">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <div id="myDIV" class="header">
    <h2>Add a task</h2>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Write a task...">
    <input type="text" id="myInput2" placeholder="Estimated time...">
    <input type="text" id="myInput3" placeholder="Week...">
    <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn" value="save" onClick="save()">Add</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


<ul id="tehtavat">
</ul>
```

I also get this error in the console:

> index.html Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'setItem' on
>   'Storage': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.

Answer (score 5):

When you want to save value to localstorage you need to pass a value as second attribute. First one is the key.

```
localStorage.setItem('myInput', myValue);
```

Think of localstorage as list of `key / value` pairs.

Besides, you want to write data to localstorage manually each time your data changes, so let's say on `keyup` event:

```
document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('keyup', function(event){
    localStorage.setItem('inputValue', event.target.value);
})
```

And i can imagine that on load, you want to bring this value back;

```
var inputValue = localStorage.getItem('inputValue');

if(inputValue) {  //just check if there's value saved
    document.getElementById('myInput').value = inputValue;
}
```

Please take into consideration that i typed code out of my head without testing it, so there are some typos possible. You can as well maybe try to solve typos on your own.

Comment: I tried that! But I still get a error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEvenListener' of null"

<script>
 document.getElementById('#myInput').addEvenListener('keyup', function(event){
    localStorage.setItem('inputValue', event.target.value);
})
var inputValue = localStorage.getItem('inputValue');

if(inputValue) {  //just check if there's value saved
    document.getElementById('#myInput').value = inputValue;
}

</script>

Comment: shit, right, made a typo `document.getElementById('#myInput')` should be `document.getElementById('myInput')`

Comment: Still not working. I got:

Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).addEvenListener is not a function

Comment: now, i made some other typo. There's no even listener,  but event listener

Comment: @ochi i used his html but the answer saves/reads only the first input box.

Comment: @ochi Yes I can see that locastorage is working now! But nothing is saved  :(  And also one item can be saved in the locastorage. Atleast 5 needs to be saved.

Comment: @Jokamutta then maybe you need to be inspired from example of the one piece saved and loaded from localstorage? Analyze it and then write your own piece? Do you want to learn how to do that or just have it done and never code again?

Comment: Well, I don't really know much about javascript so I could really need some help.

Comment: @jokamutta Well, that here is beyond helping. Remember we are here to help you learn, not show you how. If you are unsuccesful in trying to replicate one example to three copies than you should at least try much harder to describe your problems in a more understandable way.

Comment: So right now this ToDo site that I am working on can add tasks and they are saved in the local storage, but it is not saved in the page when I refresh the page  :((

Answer (score -1):

Want to store string? Store like this:

- `localStorage.setItem("myInput", "valueFromInput")`

Get like this:

- `localStorage.getItem("myInput")`

Want to store array or object? Store like this :

- *Note* : `localStorage` can only store strings
  so we need convert array into a string before storing.
  Convert looks like this :

  ```js
   var data = JSON.stringify('{myData: "myData"}');
   localStorage.setItem("myInput", data)
  ```

Get data like this:

- `var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myInput"))`